# multiplication between 4D and 4D tensors not yet supported

Tags: lua, multiplication, torch, tensor

In Lua/torch7, I have two tensors each of 4 dimensions when I try to multiply them I got this error multiplication between 4D and 4D tensors not yet supported

Is there any alternative to multiply two tensor of 4 dimensions in lua ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which package are you using?  Plain Lua does not know about tensors.

Comment: I use luarocks/torch7

Comment: Mathematically multiplication of two 4D tensors is meaningless or ambiguous at best.  If you want to do elementwise multiplication you can do `x:map(y, function(xx, yy) return xx*yy end)` as described in the [docs](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/dde9e56fb61eee040d7f3dba2331c6d6c095aee8/doc/tensor.md#self-maptensor-functionxs-xt).